# Cleanup HTML with PHP to create clean string

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I've got a bunch of HTML data that I'm writing to a PDF file using PHP. In the PDF, I want all of the HTML to be stripped and cleaned up. So for instance:

```
<ul>
    <li>First list item</li>
    <li>Second list item which is quite a bit longer</li>
    <li>List item with apostrophe 's 's</li>
</ul>
```

Should become:

```
First list item
Second list item which is quite a bit longer
List item with apostrophe 's 's
```

However, if I simply use `strip_tags()`, I get something like this:

```
   First list item&#8232;

   Second list item which is quite a bit
longer&#8232;

   List item with apostrophe &rsquo;s &rsquo;s
```

Also note the indentation of the output.

Any tips on how to properly cleanup the HTML to nice, clean strings without messy whitespace and odd characters?

Thanks :)

Comment: I doubt that `strip_tags()` alone will encode your entities. Are you sure you're not missing a call to `htmlentities` somewhere?

Comment: The indenting is exactly what I'd expect, PHP is stripping the tags, but not the extra text around them.

Comment: Do you mean I *should* or *shouldn't* use htmlentities() somewhere? At this moment I'm not. The HTML data comes straight from a database.

Comment: `htmlentities` is responsible for these things `&#8232;` (e.g.), so if you don't want them, you should not use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can decode the result of strip_tags using [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) or remove them using preg_replace:

```
$text = strip_tags($html_text);
$content = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i","",$text );
```

and to remove white spaces from the beginning of your lines use [ltrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php):

```
$content = join("\n", array_map("ltrim", explode("\n", $content )));
```

to keep apostrophes use this instead:

```
$text = strip_tags($html_text);
$text = str_replace("&rsquo;","'", $text); 
$content = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i","",$text );
```

Comment: That's great! Almost there. The only thing is that the apostrophes are now completely gone. Can that be fixed with a minor adjustment?

Comment: I used preg_replace like in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

The characters seems to be html entities. Try:

```
html_entity_decode( strip_tags( $my_html_code ) );
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked a treat for what I was having an issue with.

Answer (score 0):

use [PHP Tidy](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) library to clean your html. But in your case I'd use [DOMDocument](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class to get data from html.